# Symfony 3 firewall pattern to much root url and some other page

Tags: regex, symfony

I need to create a regex to much login, register and **root** pages:

```
/\/profile\/(login|registration)
```

this one matches things like:

```
/profile/login
/profile/registration
```

**Question**: how to change it to much also root page?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply put the firewall on `/` with anonymous and configure access via the `access_control` and `@Security` annotations?

Putting `anonymous: ~` on every single page means the security will always authenticate with an anonymous token. When you need more permissions, use the `access_control` to actually verify if the user should be logged in or not. If so, the user will be required to login and stay logged on all pages because of the firewall rule.

The best way to check this is by utilizing the following; A wildcard permission on `^/` for `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`, then use `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` to force a login for those specific pages.

This will keep your firewall a lot simpler and allows you to regulate access based on the needs.

Comment: too much access_control rules have to be writen

Comment: Rather 1 line per access control than 1 huge regex to match all kind of weird stuff

Answer (score 0):

pattern: /mysite.dev/$/

^ matches the beginning of a line, and $ matches the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain the requirements very well, but this should work:

```
(/profile[a-z/_]*|mysite\.dev/[a-z]{0,0})
```

I tested it out on these:

```
/profile/login
/profile/registration
/profile/login/login_check
mysite.dev/
mysite.dev/messages
mysite.dev/messages/
mysite.dev/*****/***
mysite.dev/login
```

And it matches those begining with `/profile` and only `mysite.dev/`.
Enjoy!

Comment: I have no information about the domain (mysite.dev was for example) I need only find url of the list in terms of regular + root url

Comment: Why didn't you make your post clearer? My answer does answer the requirements you posted...